# In how many ways can a necklace be made using $6$ identical red beads and $2$ identical blue beads?

Tags: combinatorics, necklace-and-bracelets

I got $(8-1)! /2 \cdot 2! 6!$ But it's a decimal number…

Also need to find the general formula that counts the total number of distinct necklaces made using $n$ identical red beads and $2$ identical blue beads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The blue beads can be adjacent, separated by $1$ and $5$ red beads, separated by $2$ and $4$ red beads, or diagonally opposite each other with $3$ red beads between them in both directions. That’s just $4$ distinct necklaces. Can you generalize that idea to $n$ red beads?

Comment: i did not know "necklace" was math terminology!

Comment: @David: Not too surprising, unless you’ve been doing a lot of combinatorics. Actually, the division by $2$ in the OP’s $(8-1)!/2$ suggests that he may be thinking of bracelets (free necklaces), allowing them to be turned over as well as rotated, but in this case it doesn’t matter, since with only two blue beads anything that we can reach by turning it over can also be reached by rotation.

Comment: It's interesting that you say "diagonally opposite." :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom{8}{2}$ ways to arrange the 6 red beads and 2 blue beads along a circle. The dihedral group $D_{16}$ of order 16 acts on the set of arrangements. Let $\omega$ be a rotation about the center by angle $\frac{2\pi}{8}$, $\sigma$, reflection about the line joining the mid points of a pair of opposite sides (there are 4 such reflections), $\tau$ a reflection about the line joining a pair of opposite vertices (there are four such reflections).

For $\omega, \omega^2, \omega^3, \omega^5, \omega^6, \omega^7$ there are no fixed elements. For $\omega^4$ four elements are fixed. For any $\sigma$, 4 elements are fixed and for any $\tau$, 4 elements are fixed. Thus by Burnside Theorem, the number of distinct necklaces is 
    $$\frac{1}{16}(28 + 4 + 16 + 16) = 4$$

Answer (score 0):

The number of possible necklace using $6$ identical red beads and $2$ identical blue beads are same as the number of coloring $D_8$, a [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group), with $6$ reds and $2$ blues. Find the [cycle index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index). There is $8$ rotations(including identity: $360^\circ$ rotation), 4 reflections across vertexes, and 4 reflections across lines. Thus
$$
P_G(z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_8)=\frac{1}{16} (z_1^8 + 5z_2^4 + 4z_1^2 z_2^3 + 2z_4^2 + 4z_8)
$$
But it is restricted to use $6$ red and $2$ blue. Substitute $z_n=r^n+b^n$ and find the coefficient of $r^6 b^2$. By [Polya enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem), the answer is
$$
\frac{1}{16}\left(\binom{8}{6}+5\binom{4}{3}+4\left(\binom{2}{0}\binom{3}{3}+\binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{2}\right)\right)=4.
$$

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 possible ways

1.
Two B TOGETHER that's they are separated by 0 red. 
RRRRRR BB

2.
Separated by 1 and 5 red

RRR RR B R B

Or B RRRRR B R

3

Seperated by 2 and 4

RRRR B RR B

Or B RRRR B RR

4 
Last Seperated by 3 and 3

RRR B RRR B